# Prove that $F'(t)=g'(t)f\big(g(t),k(t)\big)-h'(t)f\big(h(t),k(t)\big)+k'(t)\int_{h(t)}^{g(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\big(x,k(t)\big)\mathrm dt.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I$ an open interval and let $g,h,k\in\mathcal C^1(I)$ and $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$  with $f=f(x,y)$ continue refer to $y$. we define
$F:I\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by
$$F(t)=\int_{h(t)}^{g(t)} f(x,k(t))\mathrm dx.$$
I want to prove that
$$F'(t)=g'(t)f\big(g(t),k(t)\big)-h'(t)f\big(h(t),k(t)\big)+k'(t)\int_{h(t)}^{g(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\big(x,k(t)\big)\mathrm dt.$$

**Proof**

Let $a\in\mathbb R$ and set
$$\Phi(x,y)=\int_a^x f(u,y)\mathrm du.$$
Therefore 
$$F(t)=\Phi\big(g(t),k(t)\big)-\Phi\big(h(t),k(t)\big)$$
and so

$$F'(t)=g'(t)\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}\Phi\big(g(t),k(t)\big)+k'(t)\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(g(t),k(t))-h'(t)\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}\big(h(t),k(t)\big)+k'(t)\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(h(t),k(t))$$
$$=g'(t)f\big(g(t),k(t)\big)-h'(t)f\big(h(t),k(t)\big)+k'(t)\left(\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(g(t),k(t)\big)-\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(h(t),k(t)\big)\right)$$

I proved that if $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continue on $[a,b]\times E$ where $E$ is an open set of $\mathbb R$,  $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\int_a^bf(x,y)\mathrm dx=\int_a^b\frac{\partial }{\partial y}f(x,y)\mathrm dx,$$
so can I say that $$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(g(t),k(t))=\int_a^{g(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\mathrm dx$$

and thus simply conclude that $$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(g(t),k(t)\big)-\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}\big(h(t),k(t)\big)=\int_{h(t)}^{g(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k(t))\mathrm dx$$
or I need more argument ?

Comment: That looks correct for me. Detail is that you have to chose your $a \in I$ rather than in $\mathbb R $.

Comment: Thank you. But to my opinion $a\in\mathbb R$  is correct since $f$ is integrable on all $\mathbb R$. Moreover, $g,h:I\to\mathbb R$, therefore $g(t),h(t)\in \mathbb R$ for all $t\in I$ and are not necessarily in $I$.

Comment: You're right. My comment is wrong.

Comment: This is exactly the proof on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Alternative_Proof_of_General_Form_with_Variable_Limits,_using_the_Chain_Rule).